# Netbeans Module and JavaFX

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2

I would like to create a `NetBeans` module with an `Action` and a `JFrame`.
The `JFrame` should be shown the `performAction` is called. 
In my `JFrame` I would like to add a `JFXPanel`.

Somehow this seems to be impossible. After a lot of searching and trying different examples found on the net, I have yet no success.

The creation of a new `JFXPanel`. I had the following errors and `NetBeans` crashed :

```
gthread-error ** gthread system may only be initialized once
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please edit your question.  What is your environment, OS, window toolkit, java version etc?.  Provide a link or code to an example that fails.  Perhaps you are experiencing a [jdk bug](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6922280)

Comment: I encountered the same error when run a javafx program on sls11sp3 with jre1.7u80 HotSpot 64bit Server VM.